# How to install typings for Firebase 3 in a TypeScript 2 project?

Tags: typescript, types, firebase, npm, typescript-typings

`npm install @types/firebase --save-dev` installs type definition files for v2.4.30 not v3.

My guess is that they might not be available via npm yet. Am I correct?

Note: In TypeScript v2 type definition files are installed via npm, the typings tool is no longer used.

Comment: i am having same problem as well.. Have you found a way to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

typings are included, so `npm install firebase` and that's all

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue. As Maciej says, it is available in the package. However, the definition was not being picked up in the node_modules/firebase/* path.  As a work-around, I included the file in my 'include' array in my tsconfig.json. (I removed from node_modules since typing include not functioning and used reference to my bower install).

```
"include": [
        "src/app/**/*.ts",
        "src/components/**/*.ts",
        "bower_components/firebase/firebase.d.ts"
]
```

I did this because if I used 'types' or 'typeRoots', it overrides the /node_modules/@types lookup.